# creating a draggable div with injected jquery script

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a draggable div on top of all elements in a loaded page using extension. I have injected jquery script and following codes. this is  in my js file (copied from http://coursesweb.net/jquery/jquery-ui-draggable-drag)

```
$("body").append('<div id="dg2">hello world</div>');
$('#dg2').draggable({
   cursor: 'pointer',      // sets the cursor apperance
   opacity: 0.35,          // opacity fo the element while it's dragged
   stack: $('#dg2'),       // brings the '#dg1' item to front
});
```

this is in the css file

```
#dg2 {
    width:180px;
    height:100px;
    margin:8px;
    top:150px;
    z-index:1000;
    background:#a7daa8;
}
```

I see the div is created at the bottom of the page. And it can't drag and move.
how to create it on the middle and make it able to move? Please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anandnat/aBRt5/

Comment: oops. then something wrong in the injection of jquery-ui. thanks. thanks a lot. . .:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is working fine.. May be you haven't included jquery ui script tag in ur html
make sure of that.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

see this working link

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhinsg/dszk8/)